# Showing active menu on a drop down side menu on Bootstrap (AdminLTE)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, menu, adminlte

I want to highlight the active page on the side bar menu.
I am using Bootstrap (AdminLTE).

I have tried a number of javascript ways to no avail. Kindly anyone help out. Below is the side bar menu.

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu" >
  <li class=""><a href="/dashboard"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a> </li>
  <br>
  <li class="treeview">
    <a href=""> <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i> <span> Account Configuarion</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i> </a>
    <ul class="treeview-menu">
      <li class="treeview">
        <a href=""> <i class="fa fa-mobile fa-lg"></i> <span>M-PESA C2B</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i> </a>
        <ul class="treeview-menu">
          <li class=""><a href="/c2b"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>C2B Settings</a></li>
          <li class=""><a href="/online-checkout"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Online CheckOut</a></li>
          <li class=""><a href="/stk-push"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> STK Push</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="treeview">
        <a href=""> <i class="fa fa-mobile fa-lg"></i> <span>M-PESA B2C</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i> </a>
        <ul class="treeview-menu">
          <li><a href="b2c-documentation"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>  B2C Settings</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="treeview">
        <a href=""> <i class="fa fa-send"></i> <span>SMS</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i> </a>
        <ul class="treeview-menu">
          <li class=""><a href="/sms-setting"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>SMS Settings</a></li>
          <li class=""><a href="/subscription"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>Subscription SMS Settings</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="treeview ">
    <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i> <span>Account Info</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i> </a>
    <ul class="treeview-menu">
      <li class=""><a href="buy-units"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Buy Units</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="/account-details"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>Account Details</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="/users"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>Account Users</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I tried with this javascript code but ends up opening all the dropdowns. All the same, it does highlight the current item. But I would want the other items remain closed and only active remains open.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var url = window.location; 
        var element = $('ul.sidebar-menu a').filter(function() {
        return this.href == url || url.href.indexOf(this.href) == 0; }).parent().addClass('active');
        if (element.is('li')) { 
             element.addClass('active').parent().parent('li').addClass('active')
         }
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 14):

/** Try this ** >
    for sidebar and treeview menu in adminLTE, it will add active when clicked and remove any previous active class
/** to add active class and remove previously clicked menu */

```
var url = window.location;
// for sidebar menu but not for treeview submenu
$('ul.sidebar-menu a').filter(function() {
    return this.href == url;
}).parent().siblings().removeClass('active').end().addClass('active');
// for treeview which is like a submenu
$('ul.treeview-menu a').filter(function() {
    return this.href == url;
}).parentsUntil(".sidebar-menu > .treeview-menu").siblings().removeClass('active menu-open').end().addClass('active menu-open');
```

Comment: Add **"menu-open"** class with "active" class for .treeview-menu.  Like :  $('ul.treeview-menu a').filter(function() {
    return this.href == url;
}).parentsUntil(".sidebar-menu > .treeview-menu").siblings().removeClass('active **menu-open**').end().addClass('active **menu-open**');

Comment: This should be the correct answer, worked perfectly!

Answer (score 4):

Finally I figured it out!

I included the script below;

```
<script>
 /** add active class and stay opened when selected */
var url = window.location;

// for sidebar menu entirely but not cover treeview
$('ul.sidebar-menu a').filter(function() {
   return this.href == url;
}).parent().addClass('active');

// for treeview
$('ul.treeview-menu a').filter(function() {
   return this.href == url;
}).parentsUntil(".sidebar-menu > .treeview-menu").addClass('active');
    </script>
```

Then included `<a href="#"> </a>` on all `<ul class="treeview-menu">` I believe this prevented the lists from opening unless clicked.

This ultimately sorted everything.

Answer (score 3):

Please check below-mentioned solution :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
  var url = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
  $('.treeview-menu li').removeClass('active');
  $('[href$="'+url+'"]').parent().addClass("active");
  $('.treeview').removeClass('menu-open active');
  $('[href$="'+url+'"]').closest('li.treeview').addClass("menu-open active");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hello there.. I did try this out but does not open the submenus.

Comment: Please check my updated answer, I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:v2.3.0

```
    var url = window.location;

// for sidebar menu entirely but not cover treeview
        $('ul.sidebar-menu a').filter(function() {
            return this.href == url;
        }).parent().addClass('active');

// for treeview
        $('ul.treeview-menu a').filter(function() {
            return this.href == url;
        }).parentsUntil(".sidebar-menu > .treeview-menu").addClass('active');
```

Comment: Its working good for top level but after redirection menu is not in the active state.

Comment: Working well, just put this code in your footer file.

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE:** This code for new **AdminLTE 3** dev with bootstrap 4

```
var url = window.location;
const allLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item a');
const currentLink = [...allLinks].filter(e => {
  return e.href == url;
});

currentLink[0].classList.add("active")
currentLink[0].closest(".nav-treeview").style.display="block";
currentLink[0].closest(".has-treeview").classList.add("active");
```

Comment: if the link is not a tree view there is an error TypeError: currentLink[0].closest(...) is null

Answer (score 2):

Adminlte4

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    const url = window.location;

    $('ul.nav-sidebar a').filter(function() {
        return this.href == url;
    }).parent().addClass('active');

    $('ul.nav-treeview a').filter(function() {
        return this.href == url;
    }).parentsUntil(".sidebar-menu > .nav-treeview").addClass('menu-open');

    $('ul.nav-treeview a').filter(function() {
        return this.href == url;
    }).addClass('active');

    $('li.has-treeview a').filter(function() {
        return this.href == url;
    }).addClass('active');

    $('ul.nav-treeview a').filter(function() {
        return this.href == url;
    }).parentsUntil(".sidebar-menu > .nav-treeview").children(0).addClass('active');

});
```

Comment: This also works for lattest version 3.0.5  thank u budy good answer. Works a charm

Answer (score 2):

I don't want this question to be polluted by another answer but none of them worked for AdminLTE-3.0.1.So I created an updated solution.Here is

```
const url = window.location;
/*remove all active and menu open classes(collapse)*/
$('ul.nav-sidebar a').removeClass('active').parent().siblings().removeClass('menu-open');
/*find active element add active class ,if it is inside treeview element, expand its elements and select treeview*/
$('ul.nav-sidebar a').filter(function () {
    return this.href == url;
}).addClass('active').closest(".has-treeview").addClass('menu-open').find("> a").addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone need to fix this on Admin LTE 4 this is working:

```
<script>
    /** add active class and stay opened when selected */
    var url = window.location;

    // for sidebar menu entirely but not cover treeview
    $('ul.nav-sidebar a').filter(function() {
        return this.href == url;
    }).addClass('active');

    // for treeview
    $('ul.nav-treeview a').filter(function() {
        return this.href == url;
    }).parentsUntil(".nav-sidebar > .nav-treeview").addClass('menu-open').prev('a').addClass('active');
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This a follow up to GMK Hussain answer for AdminLTE 3. I ran into the null issue and undefined in his code(undefined because I have some pages that are not in nav links at all). I would get jS console errors. Here is what I am using:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
var url = window.location;
const allLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item a');
    const currentLink = [...allLinks].filter(e => {
    return e.href == url;
    });

    //fix for "cannot read property 'style' of null" on windows.location urls not in the nav, indefined on edit/create pages with id number
    if (typeof currentLink[0] !== 'undefined') {
        if (currentLink[0].closest(".nav-treeview") !== null) {
            currentLink[0].classList.add("active");
            currentLink[0].closest(".nav-treeview").style.display = 'block';
            currentLink[0].closest(".has-treeview").classList.add("active");
            currentLink[0].closest(".has-treeview").classList.add("menu-open");
        }
    }

});
```

I also added: currentLink[0].closest(".has-treeview").classList.add("menu-open");
This will toggle the collapsing of the higher level item possible, without it you had to click the higher level nav twice before it would toggle close.

Answer (score 0):

Solution without JQuery :

**JS Code :**

```
function isActiveElement (route, device, domain, classAsked) {

  var pathName = window.location.pathname;
  var routeName = pathName.split("/")[1];
  var deviceName = pathName.split("/")[2];
  var domainName = pathName.split("/")[3];
  var className = ""

  if(route !== "" && routeName === route) {
    className = classAsked;
  }
  if(domain !== "" && domainName !== domain) {
    className = "";
  }
  if(device !== "" && deviceName !== device) {
    className = "";
  }

  return className;
}
```

**HTML Code :**

```
<li className={"nav-item has-treeview " + isActiveElement(route, "", domain,  "menu-open")}>
        <a href="#" className={"nav-link " + isActiveElement(route, "", domain, "active")}>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm using this code to add active class depending of the page.

This is working ok except for multi level submenus any clue how to fix this,

add `active` class and stay opened when selected

```
 var url = window.location;
  // for sidebar menu entirely but not cover treeview
  $('ul.sidebar-menu a').filter(function() {
  return this.href == url;
  }).parent().addClass('active');
  // for treeview
  $('ul.treeview-menu a').filter(function() {
  return this.href == url;
  }).closest('.treeview').addClass('active');

      **HTML**
  <li class="treeview">
     <a href="#">
     <i class="fa fa-gears"></i>
     <span>Settings</span>
     <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
     </a>
     <ul class="treeview-menu">
        <li>
           <a href="#">
           <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
           Specials Settings
           </a>
           <ul class="treeview-menu">
              <li><a href="setting1.php">Setting 1</a></li>
           </ul>
        </li>
     </ul>
  </li>
```

Comment: You seem to be asking to fix your code, not answering the question.